# Django use of login() and authenticate() with a model that is not of BaseUserManager

Tags: python, django

Is it possible in Django to use login() and authenticate() with a model that is not of BaseUserManager? i.e Can I do this:

```
class RecipientAuth(object):
    def authenticate(self, mobile=None):
        """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
        try:
            user = Recipient.objects.get(mobile=mobile)

        except Recipient.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**login:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
user = authenticate(mobile=mobile)
login(request, user)
```

**on a model like this:**

```
class Recipient(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(validators=[validate_mobile])
```

I have tried and get:

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails, because your authentication backend doesn't follow the required protocol. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend):

> Either way, authenticate should check the credentials it gets, and it should return a User object that matches those credentials, if the credentials are valid. If they’re not valid, it should return None.

You need to add `return user`:

```
try:
   user = Recipient.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
   return user
except Recipient.DoesNotExist:
   return None
```